# How to use Resource Tokens to initialize DocumentClient in .NET API

Tags: permissions, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a Middle-Ware that creates users and permissions and serves the tokens to my client as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens).

However, I have not had success in using the tokens to connect to my azure database. I have tried both using the Token as plain `String`s and the complete `IList<Permission>` of the user's permissions in the appropriate [DocumentClient constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet).

Here are my users permissions:

```
{
    "_rid": "vPAMAAVaBgA=",
    "Permissions": [
        {
            "permissionMode": "All",
            "resource": "dbs/vPAMAA==/colls/vPAMAO7LQQA=/",
            "id": "service.dataPK",
            "_rid": "vPAMAAVaBgBk3LOBwSFjAA==",
            "_self": "dbs/vPAMAA==/users/vPAMAAVaBgA=/permissions/vPAMAAVaBgBk3LOBwSFjAA==/",
            "_etag": "\"00001c00-0000-0000-0000-5aa58bba0000\"",
            "_ts": 1520798650,
            "_token": "type=resource&ver=1&sig=6Dr2xKx660ZVcCO2mBbigQ==;Pl2S/djma1b8CjrmBeiIKzu4bhUgXLzaf9heZeK2UjAPihO9PfGLItQYLMt64TROG5b9H974WHhdT4L8oDREdpjA674MY/dMBqoT3AI7GkfKU/5/+HurJGRAHnwUoHlxjvasO7vsWtLln1tWlQlZSypcmF/Qey8QM+PIdJVsBWxDr2tJLW5GXCZ5BO3cFTP28qjOJ54wY7H2rxb9tqPywfnEWd27E7WtWlbqeoaOPTJX7yjFdmaaULOgIIHXq8dJ;"
        }
    ],
    "_count": 1
}
```

I use the `_token` as is in the `DocumentClient` constructor. **Is this correct**?
This is the collection i want access to:

```
{
    "id": "service.data",
    "indexingPolicy": {
        "indexingMode": "consistent",
        "automatic": true,
        "includedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/*",
                "indexes": [
                    {
                        "kind": "Range",
                        "dataType": "Number",
                        "precision": -1
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "Range",
                        "dataType": "String",
                        "precision": -1
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "Spatial",
                        "dataType": "Point"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "excludedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/'_OLD'/*"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_rid": "vPAMAO7LQQA=",
    "_ts": 1518383426,
    "_self": "dbs/vPAMAA==/colls/vPAMAO7LQQA=/",
    "_etag": "\"00001f11-0000-0000-0000-5a80b1420000\"",
    "_docs": "docs/",
    "_sprocs": "sprocs/",
    "_triggers": "triggers/",
    "_udfs": "udfs/",
    "_conflicts": "conflicts/"
}
```

Do i have to reflect the correct database and/or collection in the Endpoint-URI?

When I use the token I get the exception

```
Unauthorized, The input authorization token can't serve the request
```

When I try to use the (non-null) PermissionFeed the Constructor throws

```
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
bei Microsoft.Azure.Documents.AuthorizationHelper.IsResourceToken(String token)
bei Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(Uri serviceEndpoint, IList`1 resourceTokens, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel)
bei Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(Uri serviceEndpoint, IList`1 permissionFeed, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel)
```

I have been chewing away on this for two days now without luck. Everything else has been a walk in the park working with Cosmos DB but this is driving me insane because I cannot seem to find any example where an AuthToken is used with the .NET API.

The server's time-zone is different from the client (where i am also running the middleware under development) - but this can't be a problem, right? I use UTCNow to compare the expiry time as in the example, but creating the permissions is completely up to Cosmos DB...?

Answer (score 0):

**Turns out I was using the wrong constructor.**

When I started out developing I was using the DocumentClient constructor that takes the (master-)key as `SecureString`. Then I just plugged in the token in my current Interface (specifically a method called `SetAuthKey(string plainTextKey)`) and internally, the - in this case wrong - constructor was called.

With the right constructor, *it just works.*

Maybe this will help some other soul on this planet, so it was worth the pain.